# Prevent part of Typescript code to be compiled

Tags: typescript

I have class A and class B, which extends class A. Class A has a method which accepts AProperties enum as first argument. Class B has the same method which accepts AProperties or BProperties enum as first argument.

```
enum AProperties {
    X,
    Y
}

enum BProperties {
    Z,
    W
}

class A {
    setProperty(property: AProperties, value: number) {

    }
}

class B extends A {
    setProperty(property: AProperties | BProperties, value: number) {

    }
}
```

setProperty method of class B is added only for typescript editor to know that this method can accept both AProperties and BProperties. When compiled to JavaScript, having setProperty in classB doesn't make any sense as it is 100% identical to classA method.

Is there a way to prevent this method to be compiled in JavaScript? I guess some comment before the method could do the job.

Comment: Not sure if possible in your situation, but can't you use an interface instead of extending `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's a way of asking the compiler to skip over code without commenting it out, but you can design things a bit differently and avoid the need to add implementation of the method in the child class:

```
enum AProperties {
    X,
    Y
}

enum BProperties {
    Z,
    W
}

class Base<T> {
    setProperty(property: T, value: number) {
        // ...
    }
}

class A extends Base<AProperties> {}

class B extends Base<AProperties | BProperties> {}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20AProperties%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20X%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Y%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20BProperties%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Z%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20W%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09setProperty(property%3A%20T%2C%20value%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20Base%3CAProperties%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20Base%3CAProperties%20%7C%20BProperties%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A))

This approach adds another class (`Base`) which actually has the implementation of `setProperty` and that happens just once, and in `A` and `B` you just declare the type of the `property` enum.

There's a [discussion/suggestion to have default generic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2175) which (when it's implemented) will make it easier, something like:

```
class A<T = AProperties> {
    setProperty(property: T, value: number) {}
}

class B extends Base<AProperties | BProperties> {}
```

But for now you'll need the `Base` class.

---

#### Edit

I thought of another solution, which you'll probably like better as it doesn't require the other class (`Base`):

```
interface Base<T> {
    setProperty(property: T, value: number);
}

class A implements Base<AProperties> {
    setProperty(property: AProperties, value: number) {
        // ...
    }
}

class B implements Base<AProperties | BProperties> {
    setProperty: (property: AProperties | BProperties, value: number) => void;
}

let a = new A();
a.setProperty(AProperties.X, 4);

let b = new B();
b.setProperty(AProperties.X, 4);
b.setProperty(BProperties.W, 4);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20AProperties%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20X%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Y%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20BProperties%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Z%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20W%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09setProperty(property%3A%20T%2C%20value%3A%20number)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20implements%20Base%3CAProperties%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09setProperty(property%3A%20AProperties%2C%20value%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20implements%20Base%3CAProperties%20%7C%20BProperties%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09setProperty%3A%20(property%3A%20AProperties%20%7C%20BProperties%2C%20value%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Aa.setProperty(AProperties.X%2C%204)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0Ab.setProperty(AProperties.X%2C%204)%3B%0D%0Ab.setProperty(BProperties.W%2C%204)%3B))

Comment: By the way, how this should look like if class B extends class A?

Comment: You'll need to add generics to `A` for that, and that probably won't be convenient (at least until there's support for default generics type). So I suggest to have the `Base` class in which you hold what's shared for both `A` and `B` and then only `Base<T>` is generic.